# calling controller using JQuery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a user control contains  3 textboxes and a button
 added to a aspx page .  When clicked it should make a ajax call to controller and pass data of textboxes and it should return a message....how can i do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" />
<input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" />
<input type="text" name="baz" id="baz" />
<%= Html.ActionLink("send to controller", "Ajax", "Home", null, new { id = "ajaxLink" }) %>
```

and in a separate javascript file you could ajaxify this link:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ajaxLink').click(function() {
        var data = { 
            foo: $('#foo').val(),  
            bar: $('#bar').val(),  
            baz: $('#baz').val()
        };
        $.getJSON(this.href, data, function(result) {
            alert(result.message);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and the corresponding controller action which will receive the call and return JSON:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Ajax(string foo, string bar, string baz)
    {
        // TODO: do something with the arguments

        return Json(
            new { message = "Thanks for sending info" }, 
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT: Removed the "new" keyword when assigning the value for `var data`.

Comment: I have copied and pasted this code into template .net mvc 3 project to test and the binding of the variables to foo, bar, baz on the action method Ajax are all coming up as null.