# How to pass values from a ascx page to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how to pass values from ascx page contains [ 3 textboxes] to controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an HTML `<form>`. Example:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" })) { %>
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <input type="text" name="baz" />
    <input type="submit" value="go go" />
<% } %>
```

and then AJAXify this form:

```
$(function() {
   $('#myForm').submit(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: this.action,
           type: this.method,
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           success: function(result) {
               alert(result.message);
           }
       });
       return false;
   });
});
```

and then have a controller action which will handle the submission:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string foo, string bar, string baz)
{
    // TODO: process something ...
    return Json(new { message = "Thanks for submitting" });
}
```

Also if you want to use a normal link instead of a `<form>` with submit button don't forget to review [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387140/calling-controller-using-jquery-ajax-calls).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty basic HTML forms kind of stuff:

In HTML:

```
<form action="/Route/To/Your/Controller/Action" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="yourKeyName" />
</form>
```

Via JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/Route/To/Your/Controller/Action',
   data:
   {
       yourKeyName: $('#yourInputElement').val()
   },
   success: function(data)
   {
       // Do Stuff on success
   }
});
```